# Disabling the fullscreen editing view for soft keyboard input in landscape?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

On Android devices that use soft keyboards, I want to prevent the fullscreen keyboard editing view (shown below) from appearing when in landscape mode (i.e. I want to see only the soft keyboard itself and my view behind it).

I assume this can be achieved using the `setExtractViewShown(false)` method on `InputMethodService`, but I am unable to access the default instance of this and do not want to implement a custom input method.

[image: Android fullscreen editing view]

**Edited to add:** the view to which input is going is not a `TextView` (it's a `View` with a custom `InputConnection` implementation), so `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"` won't work here.

Comment: Let try to see it. It's good for you. [Look to this one][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648401/how-to-open-only-half-keyboard-in-landscape-mode

Comment: i have a similar problem :( you might have any idea? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36914290/android-soft-keyboard-in-a-fullscreen-surface-view

Comment: how to apply this throughout the whole app.We are not going to add the attribute-value in every edittext in xml.

Comment: Many of the answers below recommend using `flagNoExtractUi` or `IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI`. However,in the documentation for [`IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo#IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI), which corresponds to `flagNoExtractUi`, it states that "Using this flag is discouraged and it may become deprecated in the future", so `flagNoFullscreen` is the recommended option.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

I **finally** answered my own question:

The extract UI (i.e. the fullscreen editing mode) can be disabled at the point at which the input connection is hooked up:

```
@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {

    outAttrs.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI;

    // etc.
}
```

Comment: just simply put in your xml file android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"

Comment: jnic, where did you do that override at in the soft keyboard code? SoftKeyboard.java? I tried the same override and error'd out.

Comment: hey jnic. I am doing it in the same way but its not working for me.. i am still getting fullscreen keyboard editing view.

Comment: You'll probably want to add the flag to the options instead of overriding what ever options were being passed in like this: `outAttrs.imeOptions |= EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI;`

Comment: @Swati I think he means to put this method under every `EditText` `View` you want the full screen styled to be disabled.

Comment: @user726518 how to apply this attribute on the searchbox item in action bar ?

Comment: It's enough to just add android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi" inside a particular EditText element.

Comment: better to use flagNoFullscreen as it does not lock editing options and drag-and-drop on N between activities

Comment: There is not exact implementation. where should it be used and what should return in method.

Comment: The only thing worked when using custom View to handle keyboard. Thanks!

Answer (score 131):

To do that, navigate to activity xml and paste `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"` in your code. But where should it be pasted? Have look at code of example activity xml and look at EditText:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"         
    >

    <EditText
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"

        android:id="@+id/etTextInAct"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >   
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you want more customisation options for the keyboard see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html

Comment: FYI `EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI` suggests using `IME_FLAG_NO_FULLSCREEN` instead.

Answer (score 68):

add the property `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"` to each `EditText` in your `XML` file.

Comment: This answer is too short and doesn't meet SO quality standards. Please improve it adding some additional explanations, so that it will be useful for the community and not only for the OP.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati it's exactly what you have to do... it's a very simple answer because the solution is very simple and it's just a different way of doing it than the answers above. Also, answers can't be "too short" unless they don't answer the question, IMO.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what the SO community thinks about it. The answers should not be limited to solve the OP's problem, they should be great answers in general. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138740/232931) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156951/232931), for example.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati it is a *very* specific question with only one end result (but multiple ways to solve it). My answer is an addition to the other answers on this page. **ALL** of the answers on this page are only limited to the "OP's problem" because that's the only kind of answer that can be written. Like I said, it's specific and simple.

Comment: finally, i found the answer. thank you so much @mike yaworski

Comment: @LorenzoDonati The question states that `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi" won't work here.` That would have been a much better platform than attempting to suggest readers are subjected to unnecessary rambling.

Answer (score 56):

The answer above helped me figure out the solution for dynamically added EditTexts:

```
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);
```

Answer (score 44):

Use `android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen"` to achieve that feature.

Comment: nice and better approach to write in xml. Works for me. Thanks

Comment: Note that in the documentation for [`IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo#IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI), which corresponds to `flagNoExtractUi`, it states that "Using this flag is discouraged and it may become deprecated in the future", so `flagNoFullscreen` is the recommended option.

Answer (score 14):

Also, if you want to combine multiple imeOptions programaticaly, you can use the | syntax.

For example, in order to disable the fullscreen edit view in landscape and replace "Next" key by "OK" (ACTION_DONE) in keyboard, you can use:

```
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE | EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);
```

Answer (score 12):

My solution:

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|flagNoFullscreen"
```

Comment: This is a more up-to-date answer.

Answer (score 9):

If you're modifying the IME directly you can prevent it from ever displaying an ExtractedView by overriding [`onUpdateExtractingVisibility`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#onUpdateExtractingVisibility(android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo)):

```
@Override
public void onUpdateExtractingVisibility(EditorInfo ei) {
    ei.imeOptions |= EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI;
    super.onUpdateExtractingVisibility(ei);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I know it's a little bit late but for anyone who is still interested, here is my solution :
In my case I had a landscape **Activity** containing an **EditText** at top of it and I needed to implement autocomplete feature in this search **Activity**, which the overlapping keyboard caused an issue that the user could not see result of **RecyclerView**.
So I ended up having this **EditText** in my layout:

```
<EditText
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
  android:id="@+id/main_search_et"
  android:imeOptions="actionSearch|flagNoExtractUi"
  android:inputType="text"  />
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen"
```

in your edittext

Comment: Is this an answer?

Comment: I try it and it work for me! (My device is android 4.1.2)

Answer (score 0):

You can call to hide soft keyboard and clear focus from searchview.

```
public void hideKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}

super.clearFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the fullscreen keyboard in Android, use the `android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen"` property for each EditText in your XML file. It's recommended over `flagNoExtractUi`, which might get deprecated.

More details can be found in the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo#IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI)

How to use: -

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen"
    ... />
```