# soft keyboard full screen in android application

Tags: android, listview, android-softkeyboard

I have an application, where I have a list view, and list view is made upon custom adapter. I have made a suggestive search on list view. My problem is that, when I am about to type something in edit text search pan; then soft keyboard pop up gets full length by width and height in the screen, so I have no option to see whether my list view is getting changed on text change in edit text. I am being enable to see search result until I press done button in soft keyboard. I want soft keyboard pop up just pops up half the screen of my application so that I can see my listview data changes on text change given in edit text. Is there any solution related to my issue???

Answer (score 1):

Add to your EditText the attribute `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"`. This will prevent the soft keyboard to take full-screen size.

Check this answer: [Disabling the fullscreen editing view for soft keyboard input in landscape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336762/disabling-the-fullscreen-editing-view-for-soft-keyboard-input-in-landscape)

Comment: and how would i do this on a fullscreen surface view?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36914290/android-soft-keyboard-in-a-fullscreen-surface-view