# How to detect that the soft keyboard input method will cover entire screen?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I'm creating an app where users can click on a tab and soft keyboard will be shown programmatically. However, I don't want to display the soft keyboard if it's going to cover the whole screen (like extracted EditText) like this:

[image]

Detecting screen orientation might help, but AFAIK on tablets, the soft keyboard won't cover the whole screen even on landscape. So is there any other way?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. After the keyboard has popped it might be possible to determine wether some of your own views are visible, but since the user can install different keyboards(like swiftkey) with different sizes, it gets difficult to know beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it will work for you, but maybe you can [disable fullscreen soft input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4336762/1023092) instead of figuring out the detection part.