# How to avoid copy/cut options in editText when it is in full screen mode in landscape orientation

Tags: android, android-edittext, clipboard, copy-paste, clipboardmanager

I want to disable copy/cut options in editText, for this, I googled and found some good solutions from here [How to disable copy/paste from/to EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275299/how-to-disable-copy-paste-from-to-edittext), but none of this solutions is working when editText is in full-screen mode in Landscape orientation, Please help me to fix this issue, Thanks in Advance

[image]

**Note**: Similar question already asked here [How to avoid cut/copy/paste in smart phone after rotation port to land on Android4.X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969238/how-to-avoid-cut-copy-paste-in-smart-phone-after-rotation-port-to-land-on-androi) long back, since solution not yet found I was asking again

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`setLongClickable(false);`** for the edittext when the orientation is changed.

Try adding this in your activity

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE && isFullScreen()) {
        edittext.setLongClickable(false);
    } else {
       edittext.setLongClickable(true);
    }
}

public boolean isFullScreen() {
  int flg = getWindow().getAttributes().flags;
  boolean flag = false;       
  if ((flg & WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN) {
      flag = true;
  }
  return flag;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @Jyoti Jk, Actually I don't want to disable longClickable, I want that action to be enabled for my other features