# How can I tell whether the softkeyboard is in extract mode or not?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-softkeyboard

When in landscape orientation, I want to be able to tell whether the spoftkeyboard that pops up takes up the entire screen or not.
I understand this is device dependent, but how can I tell whether the current device uses a full screen keyboard in landscape mode or not?

Comment: you mean some devices shows the soft keyboard in whole screen? I have not seen any device yet

Comment: I think that when in landscape mode, ALL phones (except for the relatively very large ones) display a full screen soft keyboard unless a flag called flagNoExtractUi is turned on.

Comment: can you please describe what do you mean by full screen keyboard. Does there only the keyboard in whole screen? I just checked in galaxy y (ldpi) but in landscape mode in sms the edittext is also showing

Comment: For a user it is hard to tell that it is full screen... It looks like part of the app. Have w look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336762/disabling-the-fullscreen-editing-view-for-soft-keyboard-input-in-landscape

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that the `InputMethodManager` contains a function called `isFullscreenMode()`. I believe this is a good way to check...