# Prevent fullscreen virtual keyboard on Android (Adobe Air app)

Tags: android, air, adobe, landscape, android-virtual-keyboard

I want to prevent the virtual keyboard to go fullscreen on Android (landscape mode) in my Adobe Air made application.

I have read there is a way to do this using android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi" in the layout xml, but I have not managed to find how to do it in Adobe Air. There is a android manifest tag in the descriptor xml, but I can't make it work.

Here is how it is done in native Android development:
 [Disabling the fullscreen editing view for soft keyboard input in landscape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336762/disabling-the-fullscreen-editing-view-for-soft-keyboard-input-in-landscape)

Anyone know how to do this in Air?

Thanks in advance!

/Karl

Comment: Add this to your function that handles the focus for text fields: `event.preventDefault();`