# How can I prevent the softKeyboard from hiding textField in landscape fullscreen mode on adobe air?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe-animate

When I put an Input textField on stage in an ActionScript Adobe Air and click on it, the softkeyboard comes up but behaves differently in fullscreen landscape.  In normal landscape, the softkeyboard comes up and allows me to edit my field without hiding.  In fullscreen Landscape, the softkeyboard overlay my text area. How could i achieve fullscreen landscape without hiding my text area?

I have tried the example from adobe 'https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSfffb011ac560372f6bc38fcc12e0166e73b-7ffe.html' but it doesn't work the way expected.

I also saw some other questions on stack-overflow related to this problem and found some too but i didn't find any solution for this.
'[Prevent fullscreen virtual keyboard on Android (Adobe Air app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405379/prevent-fullscreen-virtual-keyboard-on-android-adobe-air-app)' etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit vogue, so I will just share some ideas.

Make sure that in your manifest you have the software keyboard set to pan and not to none. This will allow the keyboard to "push" your app to the textfield.

Keep in mind that the above step doesn't work properly if you are using rendermode GPU. I would suggest changing it to direct or cpu.

If this keeps happening, then most likely there is an issue with the keyboard height. I would use an ANE to get the correct keyboard height and push the view accordingly.