# InputFilter works well, but in landscape the keyboard shows the text

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, numerical-methods, android-inputtype

I'm not sure this is solvable really, but it's worth the check.
I was writing my own `InputFilter` that helps the user in inputing the right chars for ipv4 adress in an `EditText`. First stop of course is just filter whatever is not digit or '.' second step is disallow more than 3 '.' third one is to prevent more than 3 digits per group and last is to actually check the number can be (no more than 255)
In any case, I was trying to set rawInputType to `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER` so the keyboard will fit. Only then I put my input filter and only mine so the system's one will not prevent '.' chars.
This works fine, however I'm using a Nexus 4 and the native keyboard in landscape has it's own `TextView` to display the typings and it vanishes the '.' marks!
Probably because of the input type.

Anyway around this ?

Comment: Are you referring to the auto correct bar, where it shows what it thinks the input should be?

Comment: nop. when u rotate the device the keyboard is turned off, when u ask for the keyboard in landscape mode it takes over the whole screen, thus the text u see while typing is NOT displayed in your my EditText but in the keyboard's...

Comment: Possible duplicate of 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336762/disabling-the-fullscreen-editing-view-for-soft-keyboard-input-in-landscape][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336762/disabling-the-fullscreen-editing-view-for-soft-keyboard-input-in-landscape

Comment: disabling full screen ? that's the solution for writing InputFilter ? really ?

Comment: Not a duplicate, although that's one possible work around.  Is it not adding new . characters, or is it deleting old ones?  The second would be really weird behavior to me.

Comment: it's both, it doesn't show disallowed chars like '.' but in the EditText if you close the keyboard they do show up so for example a test like '192.16' will show in the keyboard view as '19216' if u add 8. u'll see just the 8 but when you close the keyboard u are left with '192.168.' the EditText works fine, that's the issue, i don't understand why the soft keyboard especially when taking over the screen doesn't take into account the Inputfilters of the user.