# AlertDialog shows wrong in landscape

Tags: java, android

I launch an `AlertDialog` in Android with an `EditText` field. When I use portrait orientation runs fine, but when I change to landscape the keyboard hides my alert. How I can I solve this?

Comment: You have your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336762/disabling-the-fullscreen-editing-view-for-soft-keyboard-input-in-landscape).

Answer (score 0):

In landscape, some android devices will cause the keyboard to fullscreen when the focus is on an editable feature of the layout (in your case, EditText).

You can flag the EditText to not fullscreen the keyboard in landscape in two ways:

XML:  `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"`

Code: `myEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);`