# How to make custom EditText and Button when I show the InputMethodManager?

Tags: android

It's a game named I'm MT3 ,developed by others...And I want to implement this feature,the custom input layout which contains a EditText and 2 buttons.

[image: The name of each button means "OK" and "Cancel" respectively.]

first,I'm using InputMethodManager to show the InputMethodManager , and this is my code snip below:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Comment: Just create an xml layout with background, edittext and two buttons. I'm assuming one is OK and one is CANCEL

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I solved the problem myself.
The answer of @Polarbear0106is right,but the soft keyboard is still in full-screen mode.
And here is an answer to disable fullscreen.
[Disabling the fullscreen editing view for soft keyboard input in landscape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336762/disabling-the-fullscreen-editing-view-for-soft-keyboard-input-in-landscape#)

It's my solution:

If you create the EditText by code,just add this line:

```
    //EditText et;
    et.setImeOptions(et.getImeOptions()| EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);
```

or if you create the EditText by xml:

just add the property android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi" to each EditText in your XML file.