# How to access the "DONE" button when holding Android horizontically?

Tags: android, user-interface, landscape

I have an editText field where the user is supposed to enter keys and a button that is supposed to start a background task (see screenshot).

[image]

But when I enter landscape mode, the button disappears and is replaced by a `DONE` Button.

[image]

So, now I need to either know, how to access this `DONE` button to tell the app to stop the background task or make my `BUTTON` reappear again.

Can you provide me with info on any of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the landscape mode, your IME went to full screen. In order to avoid that, you can add to the xml file: `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"`

or take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336762/disabling-the-fullscreen-editing-view-for-soft-keyboard-input-in-landscape) Stackoverflow's Q/A and solution from there:

```
@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    outAttrs.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI;
}
```

Comment: do I put it into the layout.xml? and where exactly?