# Disabling the fullscreen editing view on pressing SearchView icon in landscape?

Tags: android, android-layout, searchview

I am using the SearchView in an OS android project ([OSPR](https://github.com/edx/edx-app-android/pull/1106), [xml file](https://github.com/edx/edx-app-android/blob/79b40398969d6bdf0bd97786565bbf325501e940/OpenEdXMobile/res/layout/toolbar_with_profile_button.xml)) in a custom toolbar xml which is  given below, the problem is when i press the search action button on toolbar in landscape mode, its always open the keyboard in fullscreen mode, i want to avoid/disable the full screen keyboard opening.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_profile_image"
        style="@style/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/courses_profile_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/courses_profile_icon_size"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/courses_profile_icon_left_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/courses_profile_icon_left_margin"
        android:contentDescription="@string/open_profile_button"
        app:civ_border_width="@dimen/drawer_profile_image_border_width"
        tools:src="@drawable/profile_photo_placeholder" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title_view"
        style="@style/AppTheme.ToolBar.Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/courses_title_text_left_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/courses_title_text_left_margin"
        tools:text="Screen title" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end">

        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_search_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxWidth="@dimen/highest_max_width"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/courses_profile_icon_left_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/courses_profile_icon_left_margin"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/toolbar_background_color"
    app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    android:visibility="gone"
    tools:visibility="visible" />

<include layout="@layout/toolbar_shadow_view" />
```

Have already tried all of the fixes mentioned over there but none of them is working: [Disabling the fullscreen editing view for soft keyboard input in landscape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336762/disabling-the-fullscreen-editing-view-for-soft-keyboard-input-in-landscape)