# Clicking on textfield on dialog opens keyboard + area to type. How to not open this area?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have the following very simple dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50sp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Sign up to be a beta tester"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Your e-mail"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title" />


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/btnSubmitGrid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/email">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSubmitEmail"
                style="@style/ButtonStylePrimary"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:text="Submit"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnCancel"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                style="@style/ButtonStyleNegative"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="@string/cancel"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnSubmitEmail"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>





    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

I'm showing it like this

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.setView(view);
    alert.show()
```

When I click on the text field, however, it opens a giant text field + keyboard, in front of the app. Instead of simply opening the keyboard for me to type.

Is there a way to make it simply open the keyboard but not the giant blank window for me to type?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disabling the fullscreen editing view for soft keyboard input in landscape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336762/disabling-the-fullscreen-editing-view-for-soft-keyboard-input-in-landscape) `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|flagNoFullscreen"`on your text field.